# Entrenando modelo tensorflow, clasificar imagenes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Llevo meses tratando de mejorar un código. El código acierta el 98%-99% pero no consigo mejorarlo. Los fallos que comete son muy obvios y ya no se como corregirlo.

Tengo una cámara fija, que fotografía una sola plaza de aparcamiento donde unos camiones  cargan. En cada foto aparece solo un camión.

Necesito reconocer los camiones. Hay camiones totalmente distintos, en color y forma, pero otros de la misma marca, modelo y color aunque personalizados con un retrovisor, logo de su empresa, pegatina... Acierta-falla igual en casos difíciles como en fáciles.

Mis principales preguntas son:

1. ¿Cuanto mayor sea el "accuracy" de la primera epoca, es mejor?
2. ¿Debo aumentar el numero de epocas?o mi problema es otro
3. ¿Es posible llegar al 100% de accuracy?

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, estoy bloqueado.
Gracias
PD: Es mi primer post en Stackoverflow

```
import sys
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow import keras
import time
K.clear_session()

inicio=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())

data_entrenamiento = './data/entrenamiento'
data_validacion = './data/validacion'

"""
Parameters
"""

epocas=100 #original 20 to lo subo a 60 mejorando resultados
longitud, altura = 56, 56#¿40 x 28?
batch_size = 32
pasos = 430 #100, 28 y 38 funciona, Original 1000### Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 300 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
validation_steps = 88 #100,30 funciona,50 funciona, original 300(probar 57 o 76(¿4 por clase?), parece que aguanta 76)
filtrosConv1 = 32
filtrosConv2 = 64
filtrosConv3 = 32
tamano_filtro1 = (2, 2)
tamano_filtro2 = (4, 4)
tamano_filtro3 = (3, 3)
tamano_pool = (2, 2)
clases = 19
learning_rate = 0.0009#0.0004


##Preparamos nuestras imagenes

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,## y si lo quito
    shear_range=0.1,## de momento 0,1 lo mejor
    zoom_range=0.25,## de momento 0,2 lo mejor
    )## y si lo quito##  horizontal_flip=True

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

entrenamiento_generador = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_entrenamiento,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validacion_generador = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_validacion,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ="same", input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding ="same"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv3, tamano_filtro3, padding ="same"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))


cnn.add(Flatten())
#cnn.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))#Duplicado 
#cnn.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))#Duplicado

cnn.add(Dense(3300, activation='relu'))#Duplicado 50x50 2500 56x56 3136
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))#256
cnn.add(Dropout(0.10))
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
#cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr), metrics=['accuracy']) 




cnn.fit(
    entrenamiento_generador,
    steps_per_epoch=pasos,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=validacion_generador,
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

target_dir = './data/modelo/'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
  os.mkdir(target_dir)
cnn.save('./data/modelo/modelo.h5')
cnn.save_weights('./data/modelo/pesos.h5')

fin=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())
print(inicio)
print(fin)





Found 14078 images belonging to 19 classes.
Found 2805 images belonging to 19 classes.
Epoch 1/100
430/430 [==============================] - 33s 58ms/step - loss: 0.5344 - accuracy: 0.8568 - val_loss: 0.1405 - val_accuracy: 0.9611
Epoch 2/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.1466 - accuracy: 0.9592 - val_loss: 0.1153 - val_accuracy: 0.9665
Epoch 3/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.1093 - accuracy: 0.9684 - val_loss: 0.1251 - val_accuracy: 0.9654
Epoch 4/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0823 - accuracy: 0.9752 - val_loss: 0.0749 - val_accuracy: 0.9779
Epoch 5/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0822 - accuracy: 0.9752 - val_loss: 0.0699 - val_accuracy: 0.9797
Epoch 6/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0672 - accuracy: 0.9799 - val_loss: 0.0594 - val_accuracy: 0.9815
Epoch 7/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0521 - accuracy: 0.9841 - val_loss: 0.0666 - val_accuracy: 0.9818
Epoch 8/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0523 - accuracy: 0.9838 - val_loss: 0.0617 - val_accuracy: 0.9818
Epoch 9/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0537 - accuracy: 0.9823 - val_loss: 0.0464 - val_accuracy: 0.9843
Epoch 10/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0482 - accuracy: 0.9863 - val_loss: 0.0447 - val_accuracy: 0.9857
Epoch 11/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0454 - accuracy: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.0817 - val_accuracy: 0.9811
Epoch 12/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0466 - accuracy: 0.9865 - val_loss: 0.0589 - val_accuracy: 0.9854
Epoch 13/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0315 - accuracy: 0.9902 - val_loss: 0.0399 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 14/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0313 - accuracy: 0.9906 - val_loss: 0.0424 - val_accuracy: 0.9879
Epoch 15/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0407 - accuracy: 0.9875 - val_loss: 0.0467 - val_accuracy: 0.9857
Epoch 16/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0317 - accuracy: 0.9912 - val_loss: 0.0588 - val_accuracy: 0.9840
Epoch 17/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0366 - accuracy: 0.9908 - val_loss: 0.0374 - val_accuracy: 0.9893
Epoch 18/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0198 - accuracy: 0.9943 - val_loss: 0.0421 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 19/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0264 - accuracy: 0.9932 - val_loss: 0.0382 - val_accuracy: 0.9893
Epoch 20/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0242 - accuracy: 0.9934 - val_loss: 0.0395 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 21/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0294 - accuracy: 0.9912 - val_loss: 0.0497 - val_accuracy: 0.9886
Epoch 22/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0242 - accuracy: 0.9934 - val_loss: 0.0301 - val_accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 23/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0279 - accuracy: 0.9922 - val_loss: 0.0484 - val_accuracy: 0.9897
Epoch 24/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0168 - accuracy: 0.9940 - val_loss: 0.0266 - val_accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 25/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0471 - accuracy: 0.9883 - val_loss: 0.1226 - val_accuracy: 0.9815
Epoch 26/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0323 - accuracy: 0.9921 - val_loss: 0.0331 - val_accuracy: 0.9947
Epoch 27/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0254 - accuracy: 0.9937 - val_loss: 0.0363 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 28/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0153 - accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.0293 - val_accuracy: 0.9914
Epoch 29/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0206 - accuracy: 0.9939 - val_loss: 0.0540 - val_accuracy: 0.9886
Epoch 30/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0225 - accuracy: 0.9938 - val_loss: 0.0309 - val_accuracy: 0.9961
Epoch 31/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0161 - accuracy: 0.9955 - val_loss: 0.0332 - val_accuracy: 0.9929
Epoch 32/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0299 - accuracy: 0.9931 - val_loss: 0.0257 - val_accuracy: 0.9939
Epoch 33/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0220 - accuracy: 0.9949 - val_loss: 0.0299 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 34/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0187 - accuracy: 0.9940 - val_loss: 0.0592 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 35/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0217 - accuracy: 0.9940 - val_loss: 0.0276 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 36/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0119 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0322 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 37/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0209 - accuracy: 0.9956 - val_loss: 0.0675 - val_accuracy: 0.9868
Epoch 38/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0147 - accuracy: 0.9958 - val_loss: 0.0468 - val_accuracy: 0.9914
Epoch 39/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0165 - accuracy: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0353 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 40/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0139 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0461 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 41/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0292 - accuracy: 0.9935 - val_loss: 0.0910 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 42/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0180 - accuracy: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0705 - val_accuracy: 0.9918
Epoch 43/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0229 - accuracy: 0.9952 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_accuracy: 0.9932
Epoch 44/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0181 - accuracy: 0.9954 - val_loss: 0.0498 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 45/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0150 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0457 - val_accuracy: 0.9932
Epoch 46/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0080 - accuracy: 0.9978 - val_loss: 0.0382 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 47/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0099 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.0529 - val_accuracy: 0.9925
Epoch 48/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0194 - accuracy: 0.9952 - val_loss: 0.0647 - val_accuracy: 0.9893
Epoch 49/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0395 - accuracy: 0.9924 - val_loss: 0.0860 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 50/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0381 - accuracy: 0.9940 - val_loss: 0.0793 - val_accuracy: 0.9914
Epoch 51/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0135 - accuracy: 0.9961 - val_loss: 0.0473 - val_accuracy: 0.9943
Epoch 52/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0142 - accuracy: 0.9969 - val_loss: 0.0649 - val_accuracy: 0.9918
Epoch 53/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0143 - accuracy: 0.9969 - val_loss: 0.0463 - val_accuracy: 0.9943
Epoch 54/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0179 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0438 - val_accuracy: 0.9950
Epoch 55/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - accuracy: 0.9974 - val_loss: 0.0275 - val_accuracy: 0.9961
Epoch 56/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0117 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.0749 - val_accuracy: 0.9886
Epoch 57/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0197 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0681 - val_accuracy: 0.9918
Epoch 58/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 51ms/step - loss: 0.0158 - accuracy: 0.9968 - val_loss: 0.0896 - val_accuracy: 0.9925
Epoch 59/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0348 - accuracy: 0.9942 - val_loss: 0.0440 - val_accuracy: 0.9904
Epoch 60/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0178 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0626 - val_accuracy: 0.9947
Epoch 61/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0193 - accuracy: 0.9964 - val_loss: 0.0613 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 62/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0089 - accuracy: 0.9979 - val_loss: 0.0652 - val_accuracy: 0.9914
Epoch 63/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0219 - accuracy: 0.9956 - val_loss: 0.0563 - val_accuracy: 0.9932
Epoch 64/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0219 - accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0532 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 65/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0182 - accuracy: 0.9962 - val_loss: 0.0615 - val_accuracy: 0.9929
Epoch 66/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0107 - accuracy: 0.9974 - val_loss: 0.0760 - val_accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 67/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0141 - accuracy: 0.9968 - val_loss: 0.0613 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 68/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.0941 - val_accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 69/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0293 - accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.0445 - val_accuracy: 0.9918
Epoch 70/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0095 - accuracy: 0.9976 - val_loss: 0.0473 - val_accuracy: 0.9932
Epoch 71/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0129 - accuracy: 0.9970 - val_loss: 0.0370 - val_accuracy: 0.9943
Epoch 72/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0355 - accuracy: 0.9945 - val_loss: 0.0672 - val_accuracy: 0.9947
Epoch 73/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0234 - accuracy: 0.9966 - val_loss: 0.0297 - val_accuracy: 0.9943
Epoch 74/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0048 - accuracy: 0.9985 - val_loss: 0.0345 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 75/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0128 - accuracy: 0.9974 - val_loss: 0.0322 - val_accuracy: 0.9957
Epoch 76/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0258 - accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.1646 - val_accuracy: 0.9836
Epoch 77/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0172 - accuracy: 0.9970 - val_loss: 0.0488 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 78/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0278 - accuracy: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0463 - val_accuracy: 0.9925
Epoch 79/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0215 - accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0591 - val_accuracy: 0.9925
Epoch 80/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0162 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.0387 - val_accuracy: 0.9957
Epoch 81/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0119 - accuracy: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.0575 - val_accuracy: 0.9943
Epoch 82/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0116 - accuracy: 0.9981 - val_loss: 0.0450 - val_accuracy: 0.9947
Epoch 83/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0392 - accuracy: 0.9951 - val_loss: 0.0440 - val_accuracy: 0.9943
Epoch 84/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0139 - accuracy: 0.9979 - val_loss: 0.0761 - val_accuracy: 0.9939
Epoch 85/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0063 - accuracy: 0.9988 - val_loss: 0.1271 - val_accuracy: 0.9897
Epoch 86/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0324 - accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0813 - val_accuracy: 0.9911
Epoch 87/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0083 - accuracy: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.1165 - val_accuracy: 0.9904
Epoch 88/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 51ms/step - loss: 0.0118 - accuracy: 0.9972 - val_loss: 0.1604 - val_accuracy: 0.9907
Epoch 89/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0126 - accuracy: 0.9979 - val_loss: 0.0891 - val_accuracy: 0.9925
Epoch 90/100
430/430 [==============================] - 24s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0185 - accuracy: 0.9973 - val_loss: 0.1644 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 91/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0373 - accuracy: 0.9943 - val_loss: 0.0459 - val_accuracy: 0.9929
Epoch 92/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0226 - accuracy: 0.9962 - val_loss: 0.0909 - val_accuracy: 0.9889
Epoch 93/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0158 - accuracy: 0.9972 - val_loss: 0.0697 - val_accuracy: 0.9939
Epoch 94/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0133 - accuracy: 0.9989 - val_loss: 0.0580 - val_accuracy: 0.9936
Epoch 95/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0055 - accuracy: 0.9983 - val_loss: 0.0486 - val_accuracy: 0.9957
Epoch 96/100
430/430 [==============================] - 22s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0120 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.0893 - val_accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 97/100
430/430 [==============================] - 25s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0176 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.0774 - val_accuracy: 0.9925
Epoch 98/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0301 - accuracy: 0.9954 - val_loss: 0.0636 - val_accuracy: 0.9914
Epoch 99/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0094 - accuracy: 0.9985 - val_loss: 0.1299 - val_accuracy: 0.9929
Epoch 100/100
430/430 [==============================] - 23s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0254 - accuracy: 0.9970 - val_loss: 0.1151 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
2023-10-31 09:29:19
2023-10-31 10:22:53
```